# Bind value to checkbox from database in Asp.net using C#, MSSQL

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, checkbox

Am working on a registration page, Where here user has checkbox to select the location and services, Am saving the data in Database as 1 if checked , 0 if form is saved unchecked.

Now in the Edit page for the user Like profile page, am binding the data which is present in database.

I don't know how to bind the checkbox to bind if the user already checked and in database it is saved as '1"

Am using C# and Asp.net. Kindly Help

Comment: What is the column type in your database? is it `int` or `bit`?

Comment: bit, Am saving it as "true"(1), "false"(0)

Answer (score 2):

You will get either 0 or 1 from database right??
SO, store it in integer variable a;

```
{
if (a==0)
chkbox1.checked = false
else
chkbox1.checked = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert you int value `1` or `0` and then assign to your check-box checked property.
If they are string type then convert them to `int` and then to  `Boolean`

```
 CheckBox1.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(0);  // False - Not checked.
CheckBox1.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(1);   // True - checked.
```

You can use this method `Convert.ToBoolean(value)` to convert string to boolean

```
CheckBox1.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean("false");  // False - Not checked.
CheckBox1.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean("true");   // True - checked.
```

Comment: Thanks Mr. Sekar, My probl;em is how to get the value and bind it in Checkbok and it should be checked If the value is saved as True in Database

Comment: <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" 
            Checked='<%# !Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("Mycolumnname")) %>' />
In userprofile.aspx.cs file...How should i bind sir?!

Comment: `<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("Mycolumnname").ToString()) %>`

Comment: am using this in .cs
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection (@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\PRJT2\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\divlesson\divlesson\App_Data\divlession.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
           con.Open();
           SqlDataAdapter Comm = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT HobbyID,IsChecked from Hobbies where HobbyID='1'", con);
           Boolean result;
           result = Convert.ToBoolean(CheckBox1.Checked);
            con.Close();
I couldn't get my Check box Checked Even the value is 'True' in the Database

Comment: Sir , Any soultio0n how should in get checkbox binded from database?

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:checkbox id="Cluster" runat="server" checked='<%# Eval("Cluster") == DBNull.Value ? false : Eval("Cluster") %>' />
```

Comment: Kindly Tell me the code which i holud use in .cs page?

Comment: above code is of design...cluster is the column name

Comment: Say two columns in Database UserID(int) and Ischecked(bit)

Comment: Mr pranav I understood that sir, I need help how to call the checkbox in pageload in cs page from my database

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code to get the value from the database and represent it in the web form:

```
CheckBox1.Checked = rdr.GetBoolean(3);
```